# option limitMultiFileUploadSizeOverhead for jQuery File Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I see the option **limitMultiFileUploadSizeOverhead** in jQuery File Upload wiki

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

I don't really understand what it says

**Multipart file uploads add a number of bytes to each uploaded file, therefore the following option adds an overhead for each file used in the limitMultiFileUploadSize configuration.**

And even I tried many times, I still don't know how to use it and what is it for.

Comment: Thank you Aditya to correct my poor english.